# Delta queries not supported on 'users'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use delta queries on my AD and it works perfectly when I try them out through Graph Explorer, but doesn't work at all with my app, I'm getting this:

`message=Invalid request. Delta query is not supported by this resource.`

My app is an 'old' app, meaning it was registered in Azure to work with old WAAD graph api. Is this why it's not working? Or could this be because of my app lacking some permission that Graph Explorer requires? I can read 'users' without any issues, it's only delta queries I'm having issues with.

The application requests the following permissions:

`Access the directory as the signed-in user`

`Read all users' basic profiles`

`Sign in and read user profile`

Token requests are managed by the library, it's asking for the following scopes: *openid profile*

Comment: What do you mean by your token request is asking for `openid profile` scopes? Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. The library makes this request to the login.microsoftonline.com:

```GET /common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dVynGs5Isa...&nonce=6364...&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&post_logout_redirect_uri=URI```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to spend the whole day on this issue, here's what was going on. I was adding this HTTP header to the request (per some sample documentation):

`Prefer: outlook.timezone="E. Europe Standard Time"`

And that's what was breaking the delta queries request, as soon as I've removed the header - request returned delta data instead of an error. I wish the error could be more descriptive, I wouldn't have to spend so much time figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Azure AD Graph then you cannot use `/delta` queries. AAD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API are entirely distinct APIs. Calls to one are not interchangeable with the other.

If you're looking to leverage `/delta` you'll have to refactor your application to use Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'm using the new Graph API, new endpoint. The only possible issue is that my app is a 'legacy' application, registered in Azure instead of the new special page for registering graph apps.

Comment: Have you added the scopes for Graph and consented to the updated permission set?